# Reading from text file and printing it in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, c, encodings

I have a `text.txt` file and I want to read it and print its content in the Output Window of IDA Pro (Free version).

I wrote an .idc script as follows:

```
#include <idc.idc>

static main() {
    auto fp;
    auto toPrint;

    fp = fopen("C:\Users\bob\text.txt", "r"); // fp is a file handle

    toPrint = fgetc(fp);

    Message("%s is the string\n", toPrint);

}
```

[image]

But it gives me an `unknown character` as shown above. I also tried using `toPrint = readstr(fp)`, but it does not work. (same unknown character)

PS: I'm analysing a 32 bit PE file. I could not use IDAPython, as I'm using the x64 free version, so I have to resort to IDC. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variant below works for me.

```
static main() {
    auto fp;
    auto toPrint;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\[cenzored]\\desktop\\text.txt", "r"); // fp is a file handle
    do {
        toPrint = readstr(fp);
         if (toPrint != -1)Message(toPrint);
    } while (toPrint != -1);
}
```

Actually there are 3 differences between your code and working variant:

- it uses [readstr](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/328.shtml) which returns string
- It avoids using format string in Message function (but `Message("%s", toPrint)` works too)
- As in normal C I use double slash (`\\` instead of `\`) for the path of the file. This is probably an initial cause of your problem: symbols preceded by single slash are interpreted as [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) which means that the file name was interpreted incorrectly and was not opened.

Using [fgetc](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/321.shtml) in a way you did is also incorrect because it returns long or character, not a string, and Message function probably interprets is as a pointer.
I checked this on IDA 6.9. In a later versions it is probably better to detect an EOF by [value_is_string](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1221.shtml) function for this.

Comment: @w s Thank you for the help; I realised my mistake. Say, can you convert a string into an integer in IDC? eg. from '1510' to 1510?

Comment: @w s Nvm, got it. Use 'atol' command.